# Struct.new create subclass of Struct rather than object instance of Struct，does this violate the least surprise principle?

Tags: ruby, struct

Struct is really very useful for me, but when I want to take a deep look of it, I feel surprised.

Please take a look of following code and result.

code:

```
Song = Struct.new(:name, :artist, :duration)

def get_super_classes(klass)
  res = []
  while klass = klass.superclass
    res << klass
  end
  return res
end

p get_super_classes(Song)
p Song.class
```

result:

```
[Struct, Object, BasicObject]
Class
```

The result shows Song is a subclass of Struct and an object of Class.
This behavior isn't what I expect from regular new method, so I feel surprised of it？ ：-）

Comment: What do you expect? Don't understand what you mean by "regular new method".  `Struct.new(:name, :artist, :duration).ancestors
 => [#<Class:0x007fb48989ac20>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` is easier.

Comment: About "regular new method", I mean it normally returns an object of the class of which new is called,not a subclass.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean the method `new`.  (I read it as a "new method".)  Yes, it is unusual for `new` to create an instance of a class that is a subclass.  But do you have a question?

Comment: My question can be: Naming the method "new" of Struct as "generate" maybe more suitable and no surprise anymore?

Comment: If you've not read this [SO overview](http://stackoverflow.com/about) you should do so. Among other things, questions that ask for opinions are out-of-bounds.  Do not be surprised if this receives downvotes or is put "on hold".

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is the default root of all Ruby objects. It inherits from `BasicObject` so the result of your method will include `[Object, BasicObject]` for all Ruby objects.

`Struct` class works as a class generator, it generates a new class when you call `Struct.new` so `Song` is a class. In some other languages this cannot be done and that's why they introduce special syntax to define structs. There is no need for that in Ruby.

Comment: I think naming the method "new" as "generate" maybe more suitable and no surprise anymore.

Comment: Actually that would be more confusing. You call `Array.new` when you want a new array. You call `Hash.new` when you want a new hash and you call `Struct.new` when you want a new struct. You can even call `Class.new` to get a new class.

Comment: I call Array.new then I get an object of Array. But I call Struct.new ,I get an subclass of Struct.

Comment: The word "struct" is overloaded here. In the C-style programming that spawned the term "struct", the word can refer to either a definition of a structured data type *or* an instance of such a data type. In the question, the class `Song` is a struct. It would not be incorrect to call an instance of `Song` a struct as well. Those are two meanings of the same word.